# Error trying to use go_router with BottomNavigationWidget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I'm doing a go_router practice and I'm trying to use it with BottomNavigationWidget, but I can't get it to work correctly, because I have the following problem: when I try to navigate without debugging, I don't go to any page and it stays on the main page, this router:

```
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/add_screen.dart';
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/product_screen.dart';
import 'package:bops_app_v3/screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

final router = GoRouter(routes: [
  GoRoute(
    path: '/',
    builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/product',
    builder: (context, state) => const ProductScreen(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/add',
    builder: (context, state) => const AddScreen(),
  ),
  GoRoute(
    path: '/profile',
    builder: (context, state) => const ProfileScreen(),
  ),
]);
```

This main:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'config/app_router.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true),
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}
```

My bottom navigation bar:

```
import 'package:bops_app_v3/config/app_router.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class BottomNavigationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomNavigationWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      selectedItemColor: Colors.blue,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      onTap: (index) {
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            context.go('/');
            break;
          case 1:
            router.go('/product');
            break;
          case 2:
            context.go('/add');
            break;
          case 3:
            context.go('/profile');
            break;
        }
      },
      items: const [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: 'Home'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.production_quantity_limits_outlined),
            label: 'Product'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add_outlined), label: 'Add'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_2_outlined), label: 'Profile'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Esta es mi home screen y las demas son iguales solo cambia el body:

```
import 'package:bops_app_v3/widget/botton_navegation_widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: const Text('Home screen'),
      bottomNavigationBar: const BottomNavigationWidget(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in `router.go('/product')`? Should it be `context.go()`?

Answer (score 0):

For navigation using **BottomNavigationBar** you don't need context.go(), you can add those pages in *List* and use **IndexedStack** inside your **Scaffold**.
**IndexedStack** has field *index*, where you can pass index of page to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think ShellRoute would work for your requirement. Please take a look at:
[ShellRoute documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html)

If you have any doubts, please let me know and I will be happy to explain.